# How to use mapbox studio url in react-map-gl?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I am trying to use style url from mapbox studio.  I am using `react-map-gl` as a wrapper for `map-box-gl js`.

```js
<ReactMapGL
            {...viewport}
            ref={mapRef}
            mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/user__name/ckh1vbc850jll19mijutmf889"}
            mapboxApiAccessToken="pk.eyJ1IjoidW1hMTMwMiIsImEiOiJja2UweDFvbTI0MDlqMnF0djN6cGZkdmZ3In0.ZPWXqok_MC06MciSIvhxVg"
            onViewportChange={nextViewport => setViewport(nextViewport)}
            onHover={(e)=>setFeatures(e.features)}
        >
        </ReactMapGL>
```

It renders a blank screen.

ALl markers and poups are working fine, but it does't show the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

The closing " is missing in

```
mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/user__name/ckh1vbc850jll19mijutmf889}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but this is not the exactly error. I got typed by mistake in question.

Comment: What will happen if you change it to mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v8"} ?

Comment: It renders fine.

Comment: I am also able to render OSM tile. But i got problem with this tile source.

Comment: ALl markers and poups are working fine, but it does't show the tiles.

Comment: You should replace user__name in mapbox://styles/user__name/ckh1vbc850jll19mijutmf889 with a real user name

Comment: Ah, you must have replaced a real name with user__name for privacy reasons. What do you see when opening https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/your_user_name/ckh1vbc850jll19mijutmf889?access_token=your_access_token in the browser?

Comment: I had replaced the user name, but i didn't put that url here for privacy reason.